# Python Retrieve Email Addresses

Tags: python, email

I want to create a Python program to resend a email using "email" and "smtplib" package.

```
 import email
 import smtplib

 f = open('email_source.eml')
 em = email.message_from_file(f)

 email_from = em['FROM']  # '"Me" <me@xyz.com>'
 email_to = em['TO']      # '"John, A" <john@abc.com>, "Peter, B" <peter@def.com>'
```

In above case, I have 2 recipients, I want to resend to these 2 person by smtplib.

```
 import smtplib

 smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', '25')
 smtp.sendmail(email_from, email_to, em.as_string())
```

If I put the string email_to into sendmail, it only send the email to first people.  If I replace the email_to by a list,

```
 email_to_list = ['"John, A" <jphn@abc.com>', '"Peter, B" <peter@def.com>']
```

the email can sent to both person.

My problem is, can I extract the recipients to a list from the em['TO'] and em['CC'] string?

Thank you.

Comment: So your question is, how to use split the string obtained with `email` into an array? Possibly treating any edgecases?

Comment: `smtp` doesn't care what the headers say.  Just pass the recipients in `email_to` ... but you'll have to discard the "real name" (comment) part and pass in just the email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `smtp.sendmail` requires a list of addresses, according to the documentation:

> #### SMTP.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options=[], rcpt_options=[])
>
> Send mail. The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string, a list of RFC 822 to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address) […]

From the `email`-package you get a string, which the `smtp`-package then interprets as only one address.

In simple words, you need to split your *to*-address-string into a list of addresses.

How do you do this? You could do it manually, but it's best to just rely on the library:

```
import email.utils

email_to_raw   = '"John, A" <john@abc.com>, "Peter, B" <peter@def.com>'

# split into (Name, Addr) tuple
email_to_split = email.utils.getaddresses([email_to_raw])

# combine the tuples into addresses, but keep the list
email_to = [email.utils.formataddr(pair) for pair in email_to_split]

print(email_to) # ['"John, A" <john@abc.com>', '"Peter, B" <peter@def.com>']
```

After swearing a bit at the designer of the API, you wrap it up into a function:

```
import email.utils

def split_combined_addresses(addresses):
    parts = email.utils.getaddresses(addresses)
    return [email.utils.formataddr(name_addr) for name_addr in parts]

print(split_combined_addresses(email_to))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do.
I assume emails are separated with semi-colon,but you can replace ; to ,

Here is sample data

```
addresses='"Johnny Test" <johnny@test.com>; Jack <another@test.com>; "Scott Summers" <scotts@test.com>; noname@test.com'
```

Source code:

```
import email.utils
import re

def split_combined_addresses(addresses):
    #remove special chars
    addresses = re.sub("\n|\r|\t", "",  addresses)
    
    # addrs = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s<(.*?)>,?', addresses)    #colon separated
    addrs = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s<(.*?)>;?', addresses)    #semicolon separated
    
    # remove leading space in name  .strip()
    # remove double-quote in name
    addrs_clean = [(i.replace('"','').strip(), j) for i,j in addrs]

    # add missing emails without name
    emails = re.findall(r"[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+", addresses)
    for email in emails:
        if (not email in list(zip(*addrs_clean))[1]):
            addrs_clean.append(('', email))

    return addrs_clean
```